# Failed to add a categorical legend in leaflet in R using addLegend(labels)

Tags: r, leaflet, r-raster

All the files for this question are in the [following
git](https://github.com/derek-corcoran-barrios/El_Soldado):

I am trying to plot a categorical map in leaflet with a categorical
legend showing a character vector as labels:

### Load the packages

first I load the required packages

```
library(rgdal)
library(raster)
library(kableExtra)
library(rasterVis)
library(leaflet)
```

### Then I load the required datasets

```
Codes <- readRDS("Codes.rds")
LandCover <- readRDS("LandCover.rds")
```

if we look at the landcover raster it is a categorical raster that I
made with `ratify` from the raster package

```
LandCover

## class      : RasterLayer 
## dimensions : 832, 680, 565760  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
## resolution : 30.00002, 29.99993  (x, y)
## extent     : 288800.8, 309200.8, 6367272, 6392231  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
## crs        : +proj=utm +zone=19 +south +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
## source     : memory
## names      : LC_CHILE_2014_b 
## values     : 150, 932  (min, max)
## attributes :
##         ID          names IDs
##  from: 150       Cultivos 150
##   to : 932 Suelos rocosos 932
```

I want to have the name attribute as the legend

which works using the `levelplot` function from the rasterVis package:

```
rasterVis::levelplot(LandCover)
```

The data is also repited in the Codes data.frame if it works

```
kable(Codes, caption = "Tabla de atributos del mapa") %>%
  kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped", "hover"))
```

Tabla de atributos del mapa




Code


Selected






150


Cultivos




212


Nativo de Hoja Ancha




251


Plantaciones de bosque introducido




330


Pastizales




450


Matorrales




510


Humedales




640


Cuerpo de agua




800


Superficies impermeables




920


Suelos arenosos




932


Suelos rocosos

### Two tests that didn’t work

#### Test 1

```
pal <- colorFactor(rainbow(10), values(LandCover),
                    na.color = "transparent")

leaflet() %>% addTiles()  %>%  addRasterImage(LandCover, colors = pal, opacity = 0.8) %>%  addLegend(pal = pal, values = values(LandCover),title = "Land Cover", labels = Codes$Selected)
```

[image]

#### Test 2

In this second one I thought that adding the labels attribute to the
`addLegend` function would do the trick, but it does not work

```
pal <- colorFactor(rainbow(10), values(LandCover),
                    na.color = "transparent")

leaflet() %>% addTiles()  %>%  addRasterImage(LandCover, colors = pal, opacity = 0.8) %>%  addLegend(pal = pal, values = values(LandCover),title = "Land Cover", labels = Codes$Selected)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that by exploiting the `labFormat` argument of `addLegend`.
The trick is using a `transform` function within `labFormat` to re-map the IDs of the RAT to the corresponding labels.

Something like this seems to work:

```r
library(rgdal)
library(raster)
library(leaflet)

Codes <- readRDS("C:\\Users\\LB_laptop\\Downloads\\Codes.rds")
LandCover <- readRDS("C:\\Users\\LB_laptop\\Downloads\\LandCover.rds")

pal <- colorFactor(rainbow(10), values(LandCover),
                    na.color = "transparent")

leaflet() %>% addTiles()  %>% 
  addRasterImage(LandCover, colors = pal, opacity = 0.8) %>%
  addLegend(pal = pal, 
            values = values(LandCover),
            title = "Land Cover",
            labFormat  = labelFormat(
            transform = function(x) {
              levels(LandCover)[[1]]$names[which(levels(LandCover)[[1]]$ID == x)]
            }))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-11-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Hi @Ibusett could you assist with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59474422/in-r-leaflet-dont-reflect-the-latitude-nor-longitude?__=976320040